# Security to delete post by Admin

Tags: posts, jquery, security

My code is so simple like when admin delete a post by Wordpress fucntion (PHP) and do action with jQuery

```
<?php
include('../../../../../../wp-config.php');
if(current_user_can('edit_posts')){
$id = $_POST['ID'];

 wp_delete_post($id);

}else{die();}
?>
```

This is my code , what are you think about security ? this is enough ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, read something about [WordPress Ajax API](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) and about Roles and Capabilities - capability to "edit_posts" has even [Contributor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Capability_vs._Role_Table). I would suggest to check for 'delete_others_posts' to prove the user is at least Editor. Or use capability of 'manage_options' (has Administrator, not Editor).

Further, there is a [check ajax referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) function for you to help prevent entries from outside your website. Read more about [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/Wordpress_Nonce_Implementation) also.

Here is an example from the codex on using nonces when in AJAX:

In your main file, set the nonce like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
        my_string: 'Hello World!'
    };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert("Response: " + response);
    });
});
</script>
```

In your ajax file, check the referrer like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_function' );
function my_action_function() {
    check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );
    echo $_POST['my_string'];
    die;
}
```